# How to check a VideoView

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I want to check the `VideoView` if it has a streaming Video in it.

I tried this:

```
 boolean hasVideo =(viewHolder.videoView.isPlaying());
```

But it didn't work.

It's like e.g when you want to check an `ImageView` if it has a bitmap you do like this:

```
boolean hasDrawable = (viewHolder.imageView.getDrawable()!= null);
```

So how can I check my `VideoView` in this case?